# Position of new words when adding to existing words

Tags: scrabble

If an S is added to the end of an existing word, does the S have to be the first or last letter of the new word or can it be somewhere between?

Comment: what do you mean by 'in-between'?  You cant change a letter in a word so I'm assuming you mean a rare situation where you add an 's' between to legal complete words to create a new legal complete word although I'm struggling to think of any off top of head where that would work.

Comment: @StartPlayer: An "*s*" play is eluding me also - but you could run a "*g*" between "*dun*" and either "*eon*" or "*hill*", or an "*e*" between "*dun*" and "*land*", to make respectively "*dungeon*", "*dunghill*" or "*duneland*".

Comment: You could add an S between PAR and NIP to make PARSNIP, but I don't think this is what the question was about. I think they were just asking about hooking with the hook letter in the middle of the main word, e.g. adding ASK to the end of DOG to make DOGS (and ASK).

Comment: The standard scoring examples in the [rules](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) demonstrate this - see example Turn 3 on the "Scoring" tab.

Answer (score 2):

It can be somewhere in between. The rules are that the tiles placed must be in a straight line (horizontal or vertical) connected to the existing words, and there cannot be any empty spaces between tiles placed.

For more information it may help to know that this is called 'hooking': https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scrabble/Rules#Gameplay

Answer (score 1):

The "s" can be placed anywhere you like on the new word, as long as it's part of the new word. For example, your opponent has built the word "bee" vertically. Then, you can add an "s" to "bee", making it "bees". Then, using the letter "s", you can build any valid word, such as "ants", "trash", "ask" or "rats".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well done on answering the original question, not the bogus added example.